# lambda calculus evaluation

Tags: computer-science, lambda-calculus

I have a question about lambda calculus. I just read that it doesn't matter in which way expressions get evaluated.
So my question is: $(\lambda f.\lambda x.f(fx)) (\lambda y.y+1) 2$

so we can evaluate this expression like this:

$(\lambda f.\lambda x.f(fx)) (\lambda y.y+1) 2$

$(\lambda x.(λy.y+1)(\lambda y.y+1)x) 2$

$((\lambda y.y+1)(\lambda y.y+1)2)$

$(\lambda y.y+1)(2+1)$

$2+1+1$

but what if we start evaluation like this:

$(\lambda f.\lambda x.f(fx)) (\lambda y.y+1) 2$

$(\lambda f.\lambda x.f(fx)) (2+1)$ ???

So how can I continue evaluation now? I know there should be some rules not letting me to start evaluation like this but what is that?

Comment: hey Amin, please use LaTeX or MathJax to edit your question.. Your question is not readable, thereby decreasing the probability of help. An example of a readable equation could be $$x^2 + 2x + 1 = f(x) $$

Answer (score 1):

It is true that in the $\lambda$-calculus it doesn't matter in which way expressions get evaluated, provided that the evaluation ends in a normal form (i.e. in a term that cannot be reduced any further). This property is called *uniqueness of the normal form* and it is a consequence of [confluence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Normal_forms_and_confluence).

Your term does not contradict the uniqueness of the normal form. Indeed, in $(\lambda f. \lambda x.f(fx)) (\lambda y.y+1) 2$ there is only one $\beta$-redex, i.e. only one sub-term that can be reduced: $(\lambda f. \lambda x.f(fx)) (\lambda y.y+1)$. Thus, you can start only the first evaluation you wrote.

Why? If you have a term of the form $MNL$ then it has to be read as $(MN)L$, and you cannot read it as $M(NL)$. This is the unambiguous way terms are defined in the $\lambda$-calculus.

So, your term $(\lambda f. \lambda x.f(fx)) (\lambda y.y+1) 2$ is actually $\big( (\lambda f. \lambda x.f(fx)) (\lambda y.y+1) \big) 2$ and hence you cannot start the second evaluation you wrote.

---

Note that there is the same mistake also at the end of your first evaluation: the term $(\lambda y.y+1)(\lambda y.y+1)2$ has to be read as $\big( (\lambda y.y+1)(\lambda y.y+1) \big) 2$ and not as $(\lambda y.y+1) \big((\lambda y.y+1)2\big)$, hence it $\beta$-reduces to  $(\lambda y.y+1+1) 2$ and not to $(\lambda y.y+1) (2+1)$.

Comment: The order of evaluation *does* affect whether you reach a normal form or not. Two different evaluation order can't lead to two different normal forms, but one can fail to reach a normal form while the other succeeds.

Comment: @DerekElkins - You are right, thank you for the specification. I edited my answer. Anyway, note that by confluence whatever term $t$ is reached according to _any_ evaluation starting from a term $t_0$, the _unique_ normal form of $t_0$ can always be reached from $t$.

Comment: What is the reason of the downvote?